# error :reason: '-[UITextField mas_makeConstraints:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, masonry-ios-osx

error comes out when this code run：
`[ageInputTextFiled mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){}];`

  I have searched several similar problem to me ,most answer say that masonry is not link to the project successfully , but i load masonry by cocoapods ,and compile is ok. So anyone can help?thanks

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @SeanChense UITextField *ageInputText = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    [ageInputText mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make)
    {
        make.left.mas_equalTo(self.ageLabel.mas_right).with.offset(30);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.ageLabel.mas_centerY);
        make.height.equalTo(@44);
        make.width.equalTo(@120);
    }];
    [self.contentView addSubview:ageInputText];

Answer (score 0):

You need `addSubview` first then set constraints.

Comment: thank you for answering ,i have tried this way, but not work, came out the same error

Answer (score 0):

well... i found one solution. open other linker flags ,and add "`$(inherited)`",my project work just fine,error disappear.

But i don't exactly understand how this works.If someone can tell me ,i will appreciate it.